# Using Windbg to analyze possible memory leak from a dump file

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windbg, dump

this app (native c++) runs fine for hours, the used memory stays around 9MB for hours, then suddenly when I check again it goes to 15,then 20, then 29 etc. There may be hours between each checks and it stays around the same value for hours as well.
The app is not crashing, so I generated a dump file while running from task manager hoping to analyze it in windbg or vstudio.

In VStudio I can see the threads that were running, see the specific line where each thread was at the moment of the dump, see local variables etc but I can't (I guess I dont know how to) see what is being allocated that is using so much memory.

I opened the debug -memory window, see the 4 memories (1-4) but I cant make sense of it, I havent been able to find a good doc on how to use that information either.

When using windbg I load both the windows symbols and the app symbols, but when I type in: "!heap -s" I see only 2 heaps and not much information to proceed. I have followed a couple of tutorials on how to use windbg to find memory leaks with success but they are all simple cases and in all cases either the app is started/debugged on windbg itself or attached to it, but I havent found a doc where a generated dump (not a crash dump) is analyzed.

Is this even possible? If so please provide me with some pointers on how to proceed, thank you in advance

Comment: use xperf to trace this issue: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc. It gives you the callstacks of the allocations.

Comment: thank you a lot, it does seem very good, I will look into it

Comment: heh, I forgot about that one. You should definitely download Andrew's xperf-scripts from his [onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=e17bd609d227bb4a&id=E17BD609D227BB4A%2111560). The Collect Heap_Attach preset looks to me like the one that'll give you most information about your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario that you describe can be quite hard to debug, whether you are looking at post-mortem (dump) or live debugging.

The first step is to determine if the problem is a real leak - as in memory not being freed. The best way to determine that is to use instrumented code that measures the heap usage, and tracks what allocations are made, and their size, and reports (for example to a log-file) what the allocations are, and their size. Or simply keeps track of the number of active allocations.

There are scenarios where memory is not strictly leaking, your app is just using more memory, for example from fragmentation of the heap - this will make the heap grow, but it is not technically a leak. This can be hard to avoid, for example an array of strings, and you add a character to each string, every string will need a slightly bigger space. If the strings are allocated interspersed with a lot of other allocations, the space freed by each string will be too small to hold the new strings. This sort of behaviour can create small or large fragments of the heap that over time grows the heap - typically it will eventually stop growing, but it can take quite a long time, depending on what the application does, how often it allocates from memory.

Another scenario is that your application (perhaps under some circumstances) is adding new information and not getting rid of the old, and this adds up - technically and strictly speaking, not a leak. But it builds up on the heap.

However, my guess is that your application is "restarting" something, and not cleaning up after itself. In other words, it has allocated some amount of memory on the heap, then "forgets" that whole lot, and starts anew with a new set. This could be a bug in for example a "grow this object" type function, or it could be a `vector<int> *v = new vector<int>; ... v->push_back(x); ...` missing `delete v;` type of thing.

Unfortunately, like I said, it's not easy to debug this sort of things. You really have to have at least an idea of what you expect to find, and what is actually in the heap. If you have A LOT of the same type of object, and you can identify objects, you could dig through the memory dump and see if there are unusually large numbers of elements of a particular kind. But this assumes that you can identify, from a memory dump, what objects are what kind (if you have objects with virtual functions, you should be able to identify the `vptr` in the heap, if nothing else). It is NOT easy to do this, and it takes quite a lot of experience in looking at memory dumps to identify what is what, and how to determine if "this is normal" and "this not".

Look for container objects (vector, map, etc) that contain pointers to objects - check if the number of elements "seem right" for what your application is supposed to do.

You can also add logging in relevant places, e.g. printing out the size of selected container objects.

There are libraries/runtime tools that help identify memory leaks - I'm a Linux developer, so I would use valgrind, but I know there are Windows tools that do this sort of thing too. Or, like I said, implement instrumented `operator new` and `operator delete` that track memory usage - in the simplest form just a counter up and down [atomic if you have multiple threads] and keep track of how many outstanding allocations there are. If you keep that going for long enough, it should be clear if you are actually leaking stuff or not. You can then make it more sophisticated and add where (get the callstack, or some such) the allocations are made. And/or record the size of the allocations, etc.

Comment: +1 - OP might have some luck in narrowing it down by using [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to create a dump when a certain memory commit threshold is exceeded. With some luck, he'll have a dump of when the actual increment in memory is taking place and draw conclusions from there.

Comment: Thank you Mats, I truly believe at this moment that it is more of a heap fragmentation issue than a leak, I do a lot of string manipulation, (concatenation, find, get substring, replace etc). I also have a map container which stores pointers to objects but I print its size every 2 seconds and it is consistent to what I expect, it is supposed to hold as many objects as the workers threads count and it is consistent. I appreciate your comments. Apparently Windbg is not the most appropriate tool for this case in particular or the doc to use it how I intend is more scarce than what I thought. :-)